# Web server connection - fileNotFound error

Tags: java, android, inputstream, filenotfoundexception

I have a project in which my app communicates with Java web server. The connection is actually done, and the server gets all parameters it needs from the request, but my app crashes right away with exception fileNotFound.

```
try {
URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/MSGWebServer/ReadMessage?
name="+username+ "&date="+ date + "&hour="+ hour + "&message="+
txtMessage[0]);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());        
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); } //EXCEPTION IO EXCEPTION: FILE NOT FOUND
```

Server code for relevant Post:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/ReadMessage"})
 public class ReadMessage extends HttpServlet {    
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String message=request.getParameter("message");
    u.insertMessage(message);   //WORKS AS EXPECTED!
 }
```

Comment: Please show the actual stacktrace, not just the exception

Comment: I think you can skip the entire inner try block and just do `con.connect()`. You will have to add a catch for `IOException` to the outer one.